# jooq wrong date from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jooq

I am using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) to read data from a MySql database. I am reading a column whose type is 'date'. When I print the result set date is wrong. What can be the reason ?

```
Database Date        =>  2010-08-14
jOOQ result set Date =>  2010-08-13
```

this is the query =>

```java
f.select()
 .from(dal.jooq.Tables.INVOICES)
 .where(dal.jooq.Tables.INVOICES.CARRIER_ID
   .equal(UInteger.valueOf(carrier_id)))
 .and(dal.jooq.Tables.INVOICES.INVOICE_DATE.greaterOrEqual(sstart))
 .fetch();
```

Comment: Are your database and your JDK set to the same time zone? What would you get if you were fetching that value using JDBC directly?

Comment: @Lukas Eder Thanks for your post, I had a mistake ,Mysql Date and the jOOQ result set Date are equal (2010-08-14) but when i save this date to MongoDb its saves as  (2010-08-13) , should i set MongoDB time zone also ?

Comment: I can't say what the problem is, from what you posted so far

Comment: Thanks Lukas Ede,I resolved my first question , I realize that mongoDB is storing dates in UTC format anyway. Now my question is mongoDB keep System timezone as the timezone of mongodb ? , Is there any place to change those setting in mongoDB ?

Comment: The best way to proceed is to: 1. answer this question yourself, 2. ask a new question related to mongoDB and timezones