# Is mongodb keep the System timezone as it's timezone ?

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime

I'am using Java(JOOQ) with mongoDB ,

Is mongodb keep the System timezone as  it's  timezone ?

Is there any way to set mongoDB's default timezone ?

Thanks

Comment: Note to future readers, the original question leading to this problem was located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156877/jooq-wrong-date-from-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

No, mongo does not keep system timezone. In database dates get stored in UTC format:

> A BSON Date value stores the number of milliseconds since the Unix
>   epoch (Jan 1, 1970) as a 64-bit integer. v2.0+ : this number is signed
>   so dates before 1970 are stored as a negative numbers.

But most of drivers do dates conversion back to your local timezone when reading. I not sure about java driver, but in c# you can actually say driver to read all dates in utc and do conversion to appropriate time zone yourself in the client code. But by default c# driver convert dates to the computer timezone.

Comment: Thanks , But how does MongoDB convert dates to UTC without keeping the TimeZOne, To convert a date to UTC,i think converter should know the timezone of that particular Date , How does mongoDB knows that ? Is it taking from JVM ?

Comment: The drivers do the conversion client side, not the mongo database servers.